# How to add HTML using CSS (and Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hubspot

So I am using a crm to manage my website blog which isn't giving me full flexibility with HTML. I am trying to add a bar with social media icons after the 2nd or 3rd blog post. In the CSS stylesheet I got access to the post by using ".class:nth-child(3)::after". Is there any way to insert a full html div using javascript to add the social bar?
Or could I create the bar in the same html file and change the location based on the post?

EDIT: Sorry it's my first post.

Attaching the design.
[basicDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edi5F.png)

The stylesheet snippet with an example of the web page. [CSSimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C31Sr.png)

Comment: Please provide examples of any code you have already tried.

Comment: @DanielBernardi Thank you for the tip. I have just edited the post to add screenshots.

Comment: You will have to use javascript. There's no way to add complex html to a psuedo element beyond simple text.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the CSS [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) attribute. It allows you to specify elements in your CSS to be applied. It is often used in conjunction with [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and ::after pseudo elements.

Comment: I tried the ::after pseudo element. Just edited the post and attached screenshots of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, you want to display social media icons after the third blog post?

If you're using the template builder, insert a custom module with the appropriate HTML below the blog listing module. Give it a class, in this instance -> 'social-media-blog'.

Then with some jQuery you can just set it to display after the 3rd blog post.

```
var blogSocialMedia = $('.social-media-blog');
$(".post-listing .post-item:eq(3)").after(blogSocialMedia);
```

Comment: The question is waaaaay off topic. Do not answer off topic questions.